# Pandas won't separate columns in my comma separated .txt file

Tags: python, pandas

I'm aware this has been asked so many times, but it's left me really scratching my head. I have a .txt file which looks like:

"0,1,2,3,4, ....63,0,1,2,3,4.....63"

"0,1,2,3,4, ....63,0,1,2,3,4.....63"

"0,1,2,3,4, ....63,0,1,2,3,4.....63"

and so on for multiple rows.
So that's 64+64 = 128 columns separated by commas, while each row is enclosed in double quotes.

I have used the commands:

```
#Used this initially
df = pd.read_csv('test_data.txt')
#Used this after reading more stackoverflow answers
df = pd.read_csv('test_data.txt', header = None, sep=",", delimiter=',', quotechar='"', index_col = None)
```

I know sep and delimiter are the same parameters, but I tried both out anyway, I shouldn't have to specify these either because pandas chooses commas by default. 
After this I'm just using:

```
df.head()
```

And it outputs:

```
                                                 0
0   0.00,1.00,2.00,3.00,4.00,5.00,6.00,7.00,8.00,9...

1   0.00,1.00,2.00,3.00,4.00,5.00,6.00,7.00,8.00,9...

2   0.00,1.00,2.00,3.00,4.00,5.00,6.00,7.00,8.00,9...

3   0.00,1.00,2.00,3.00,4.00,5.00,6.00,7.00,8.00,9...

4   0.00,1.00,2.00,3.00,4.00,5.00,6.00,7.00,8.00,9...
```

It just reads it all as the one column, please advise on how I can read all 128 columns.

Comment: not sure with the info provided, but you can try with pd.read_table('filename',sep=",",header=None) and check if it works

Comment: @anky_91 Hi, just tried it, still only reading one column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get you to desired result:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test_data.txt', header=None)
df = pd.DataFrame(df[0].str.split(',').tolist())
```

So this will read your file, that has each row wrapped with quote marks, and pack it into single column.

Then, you split that column by `comma` and construct new dataframe from the results.

Comment: Thank you so much! Why wasn't read_csv splitting columns by comma though?

Comment: @AbdurRehmanKhan Because of the quotes, try adding `quoting=3` to `read_csv` and you'll see what happens.

Comment: Ohhhh it all makes sense now...

even though I added quotechar=' " ', must have misunderstood its purpose then.