# How to create a Pandas Dataframe from the comma separated values in txt file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a txt file which contains data as in below format

```
"column1,column2,column3,column4,column5,column6,column7,column8"
"abc,abc,abc,10,datetime,abc,abc,abc"
"xyz,xyz,""xyz1,xyz2"",2,datetime2,xyz,xyz,xyz"
"xyz,xyz,""xyz1 , xyz2"",2,datetime2,xyz,xyz,xyz"
```

I want to convert it into a Pandas DataFrame which will be having 8 columns of header same as row 1

it is different from normal/regular Dataframe question.
I tried with following code,

```
df = pd.read_csv('tst.txt')
```

But output was

```
    column1,column2,column3,column4,column5,column6,column7,column8
0   abc,abc,abc,10,datetime,abc,abc,abc
1   xyz,xyz,"xyz1,xyz2",2,datetime2,xyz,xyz,xyz
2   xyz,xyz,"xyz1 , xyz2",2,datetime2,xyz,xyz,xyz
```

I tried with other things as well like

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([line.replace(' , ','$$$').replace('"','').replace('\n','').split(',') for line in open('tst.txt')])
```

but output was different and not expected

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
0   column1     column2     column3     column4     column5     column6     column7     column8     None
1   abc     abc     abc     10  datetime    abc     abc     abc     None
2   xyz     xyz     xyz1    xyz2    2   datetime2   xyz     xyz     xyz
3   xyz     xyz     xyz1$$$xyz2     2   datetime2   xyz     xyz     xyz     None
```

So you can see here that only 8 columns should be there not 9.
datetime should be in 5th column.

**Actual output should be like,**

```
    column1     column2     column3     column4     column5     column6     column7     column8
0   abc     abc     abc     10  datetime    abc     abc     abc
1   xyz     xyz     xyz1,xyz2   2   datetime2   xyz     xyz     xyz
2   xyz     xyz     xyz1 , xyz2     2   datetime2   xyz     xyz     xyz
```

Comment: ```pd.read_csv('tst.txt', sep=',')```

Comment: Maybe this helps: [Pandas won't separate columns in my comma separated .txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52037359)

Answer (score 1):

Try pass the `quotechar` with `"`

```
df=pd.read_csv('tst.txt', quotechar='"', sep=',')

  column1 column2      column3  column4    column5 column6 column7 column8
0     abc     abc          abc       10   datetime     abc     abc     abc
1     xyz     xyz    xyz1,xyz2        2  datetime2     xyz     xyz     xyz
2     xyz     xyz  xyz1 , xyz2        2  datetime2     xyz     xyz     xyz
```

Comment: I am still not getting this kind of result. I am doing same as above still not getting desired one.